# woocommerce, showing shopping cart in admin backend

Tags: woocommerce

I keep getting this error **Fatal error: Call to a member function get_cart() on a non-object in...on line 1113**  Here is my full code

custom_dashboard.php

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-load.php');
global $woocommerce;
woocommerce_mini_cart();
```

line 1113 is located in functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 0 );

 function add_custom_price() {
global $woocommerce;

    $loop = 0;
     $item_data = array();

     foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
//content
}
}
```

How do i solve?  I want to show the shopping cart on custom_dashboard.php.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the following condition first.

```
if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 )
```

so after adding this condition your code will look like

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 0 );

 function add_custom_price() {
     global $woocommerce;

     $loop = 0;
     $item_data = array();

     $valid_for_cart = false;
            if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
                foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                     //content
             }
         }
}
```

Comment: i tried this.. i still get the error and it points to this line `if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 )` now.

Comment: Use $woocommerce instead of WC() in your code. Check and let me know if this works for you.